# Trying to set a cookie on Joomla's onLoginUser trigger in a plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, setcookie

I have a very simple Joomla plugin that I am writing which drops a cookie with an email address that another application can then use.  This is all for internal use, it will not be distributed.  Anyway, the plugin installs fine, but it won't create the cookie.  I am using the Chrome browser's Developer view to see if the cookie appears and it never does.

```
function onLoginUser()
 {
    $app = &JFactory::getApplication();

    // Get Joomla's user object
    $user = &JFactory::getUser();

    if (!$user->guest) 
    {
         setcookie('userinfotocookie-email', $user->email);

         JRequest::setVar('userinfotocookie-id', $user->id, 'cookie');
    }

    return true;
 }
}
```

Notice, I tried two different ways to create the cookie, neither works.  If I intenionally put bad code in the routine, I get an error, so I know that the routine is being called.  I guess I am missing something about how the plugins work in Joomla; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general idea of my solution which DOES NOT IMPLEMENT cookies.  I know it doesn't actually answer the question, but after discussion with Valentin (see comments) and thinking this through I realized that cookies are not a good design choice and is prone to a lot of issues. I decided to write a Joomla Content plugin instead.  This looks for a pair of {showappwithuser} tags within the content and replaces it with an iframe pointing to the URL inside the tag pair.  For instance:

```
{showappwithuser}http://www.somewebsiteapp.com{/showappwithuser}
```

This would be replaced with an iframe that points to http://www.somewebsiteapp.com?uid=joomlausername.  This passes the information to the accepting app and that app can then do what it needs to do with it.  The full code is below, and is still a bit clunky in that mostly everything is hardcoded. I need to add parameter handling so that the content creator can choose iframe settings like width, height, scrollbar access.  I also plan to integrate the encryption of the uid parameter so there is some obfuscation of information between applications.  This can really go in a lot of different directions and if written correctly can be a nice plugin to integrate any non-Joomla application into a Joomla site seamlessly. There are also endless possibilities for sending other parameter information to an app using this method.  Enjoy!

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// import the general plugin file of Joomla!'s library
jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );


// hook into the plugin framework
class plgContentShowAppWithUser extends JPlugin 
{
    // the core code to create an iframe and set it's URL source 
    // with the logged in user name from Joomla
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        $starttriggerpos = strpos($row->text, "{showappwithuser}");
        $iframeurl = "";

        if ($starttriggerpos !== false)
        {
            $endtriggerpos = strpos($row->text, "{/showappwithuser}");
            if ($endtriggerpos !== false)
            {
                $iframeurl = substr($row->text, $starttriggerpos+17, $endtriggerpos-$starttriggerpos-17);

                if (!JFactory::getUser()->guest) 
                {
                    $username = trim(JFactory::getUser()->username);

                    if (strlen($username) > 0)
                    {

                        $row->text = '<iframe src="' . $iframeurl . '?uid=' . $username . '"' . ' frameborder=0 scrolling=auto width=725>This application requires a browser that supports iframes.</iframe>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $row->text = "Your web site login could not be determined. Please correct this and try again.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $row->text = "You must login to the web site in order to access this content.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what Joomla! version you are using, but I am referring to Joomla! 2.5. I think **you forgot to pass the right parameters.** Try renaming your function:

`public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())`

I would not use setcookie() in Joomla!.  You can easily use [JSession](http://ostraining.com/howtojoomla/how-tos/development/how-to-use-sessions-in-joomla). But apart from this, it's not very clear what exactly should your plugin do.

Comment: I was reading the documentation that I found which I guess focuses on Joomla 1.5. I don't recall seeing anything in the docs about parameters. I'm actually running Joomla 1.7. As for the purpose, I want to run another app in an iframe within Joomla and want to pick up the logged in user name so I can authenticate within the app.  I don't want to write a component because the app is a .Net app.  Does that help?

Comment: I am not sure that the plugin is what you need. From your brief explanation I would build a very basic component just to hold the iframe. In the component you can use JFactory::getUser() to get the current user and to decide if to dislay the iframe or not (maybe). Apart from that, Joomla! 1.5 is rather old and diferent from Joomla! 1.6+ series. Also Joomla! 1.7 is no longer supported and an urgent update to Joomla! 2.5 is highly recommended!

Comment: We will likely upgrade Joomla as part of this project, is there a major difference in add-in writing? Although your approach makes sense, the app running in the iFrame needs to be able to read the user's name so it can do internal authentication. I thought by dropping a cookie in one app I could then read the value in another app (not a PHP app, but .Net) and give me the cross-app communication I needed.  I suppose I could make a component that passes the user name in a URL parameter as well when it populates the iframe. The cookie seemed like a better route to go, but I'm open.

Comment: Joomla! 1.7 is largely compatible with 2.5. You can you do the authentication also depends on how secure you want your app to be. Exchanging a cooking may be a reasonable solution. Have a look at this for an idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

Comment: I tried with the params and that didn't work. At this point, I have to agree that cookies are not the way to go here for many reasons. I will venture to creating a content component that will generate the iframe and set the iframe url to include a parameter with the user's name or id which the target application can then do with as it pleases.  If I structure this correctly, it should give me a plugin that would allow hosting any application in an iframe with the right params.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Valentin - I am +1 you since you helped lead me to an answer which I posted below. Thanks for your help again!